# rails validate dependent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

There have 2 tables: **Orders** and **Arrivals**. There can be many arrivals on an order. I want to validate the creation of arrivals for a specific order.

**Orders** has fields `book_id` and `quantity:integer`

**Arrivals** has fields `order:belongs_to` and `quantity:integer`

Order.rb:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :arrivals

  def total_arrival_quantity
    arrivals.map(&:quantity).sum
  end

  def order_quantity_minus_arrival_quantity
    quantity - total_arrival_quantity
  end
end
```

Arrival.rb:

```
class Arrival < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order

  validates :total_arrival_quantity_less_or_equal_to_order_quantity, on: create
  validates :current_arrival_quantity_less_or_equal_to_order_quantity, on: create

  def current_arrival_quantity_less_or_equal_to_order_quantity
    self.quantity <= order.quantity
  end
end
```

How can I make the two validations work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work,

```
validate :order_quantity, on: :create

private
def order_quantity
  if quantity > order.order_quantity_minus_arrival_quantity
    errors.add(:quantity, 'cannot be greater than ordered quantity.')
  end
end
```